# Server Side Blazor Component in .net 8, @onclick event not firing

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0, blazor-auto

In Blazor Server in .net 7 I can do this in a Page.blazor:

@message

```
<button class="btn btn-primary mt-2 btn-block" @onclick="SendMessage">Send Message</button>


@code {
    public string message { get; set; }

    private async Task SendMessage()
    {
        message = "Hello";
    }
}
```

When you click the button it outputs "Hello" on the page.

However, in .net 8 in a "Blazor Web App" (Auto, Server mixed with Web Assembly) in a Page.blazor on the server side, this button doesn't work.

Buttons in an EditForm do work but I don't want to use that, I just want clicking a button to fire an event.

Why doesn't this work in .net 8 and how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like you're server side rendering the page and getting a static page.      Check the `<Routes @rendermode="@RenderMode.InteractiveAuto" />` in App.razor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rendermode would be `Static Server` by default,here's the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#render-modes) related

add  `@attribute [RenderModeInteractiveServer]` in your component

or

add the codes below in app.razor for entire app

```
@using static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.RenderMode
.....
<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I just figured this out too, I guess that sets it for the whole app and just to set on the page I'd use this on each page? @rendermode InteractiveServer

Comment: What's the difference between putting this, @rendermode InteractiveServer, and @@attribute [RenderModeInteractiveServer] on the component?

Comment: @ rendermode InteractiveServer and  @ attribute [RenderModeInteractiveServer] are all for a single component,@attribute [RenderModeInteractiveServer] might obsolte in feature , @ rendermode InteractiveServer dosen't work in some  preview versions

Comment: `@attribute` is going to be deprecated for `@renderedmode` so the latter is the recommended keyword to use

Comment: How would you handle this if you wanted to stay on SSR?